# Retrieving the username of the current user logged in, using SQLite in android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am new to android. I am trying to make a simple app where user can update status. I would like to display the status and the current user who is logged in and updated the status. I tried some code, it gives the username but not the current user. How can i get the current user name? Can anyone please help?

UpdateStatusActivity:

```
public class UpdateStatusActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public EditText mUpdateStatusTextBox;
public Button mUpdateStatusButton;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_update_status);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mUpdateStatusTextBox=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.updateStatusTextBox);
    mUpdateStatusButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.updateStatusButton);
    mUpdateStatusButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //get the status user has entered and convert to string
            String strUpdateStatus = mUpdateStatusTextBox.getText().toString();
            DatabaseUserDetails dbuserdeatils = new DatabaseUserDetails(getApplicationContext(),null,null,1);
            String strCurrentUsername = dbuserdeatils.getUsername();
            DatabaseStatusUpdate dbstatusupdate = new DatabaseStatusUpdate(getApplicationContext(),null,null,1);
            dbstatusupdate.saveStatus(strCurrentUsername,strUpdateStatus);
            Log.d("onclickStatus",strCurrentUsername);
            Log.d("onclickStatus",strUpdateStatus);
            Toast.makeText(UpdateStatusActivity.this,"Status updated",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(UpdateStatusActivity.this,HomePageActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
```

}

DatabaseUserDetails:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_TABLE_CLASS = "CREATE TABLE  " + TABLE + "(" +
            COLUMN_USERNAME + " " + " TEXT," +
            COLUMN_PASSWORD + " " + " TEXT," +
            COLUMN_EMAIL + " TEXT)";
    Log.d("onCreate",CREATE_TABLE_CLASS);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_CLASS);
}

public void insertEntry(String username,String password,String emailid )
{
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_USERNAME, username);
    values.put(COLUMN_PASSWORD,password);
    values.put(COLUMN_EMAIL, emailid);
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.insert(TABLE,null,values);
    Log.d("insertEntry",username);
    Log.d("insertEntry",password);
    Log.d("insertEntry",emailid);

    db.close();
}
public String getSinlgeEntry(String userName)
{   SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor=db.query(TABLE,  new String[] {COLUMN_USERNAME, COLUMN_PASSWORD}, COLUMN_USERNAME + " = ? " , new String[]{userName}, null, null, null);
  /*  Cursor cursor=db.query(TABLE, null, COLUMN_USERNAME + " =?", new String[]{userName}, null, null, null);*/
    if(cursor.getCount()<1) // UserName Not Exist
    {
        cursor.close();
        return "NOT EXIST";
    }
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String password= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_PASSWORD));
    Log.d("getSingleEntry",password);
    cursor.close();
    return password;
}
public String getUsername(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    /*Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE, new String[] {COLUMN_USERNAME, COLUMN_PASSWORD}, COLUMN_USERNAME , null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();*/
    String selectQuery = "SELECT "+COLUMN_USERNAME+ " FROM " + TABLE ;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String username=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_USERNAME));
    return username;
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

DatabaseStatusUpdate:

```
public class DatabaseStatusUpdate extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "statusupadteDB.db";
private static final String TABLE = "statusuodate";
public static final String COLUMN_USERNAME = "username";
public static final String COLUMN_STATUS = "status";

public DatabaseStatusUpdate(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_TABLE_CLASS = "CREATE TABLE  " + TABLE + "(" +
            COLUMN_USERNAME + " " + " TEXT," +
            COLUMN_STATUS + " " + " TEXT)";
    Log.d("onCreate",CREATE_TABLE_CLASS);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_CLASS);
}
public void saveStatus(String username, String status) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_USERNAME,username);
    values.put(COLUMN_STATUS,status);
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.insert(TABLE,null,values);
    Log.d("saveStatus",username);
    Log.d("saveStatus",status);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
}
```

Comment: I can't see any column or field that you store current username. Can you explain what's the difference between username and current username ?

Comment: How is the username different from the current username? Shouldn't they be the same already?

Comment: @EsatIBIS Basically i jus want to display the name of the user who is currently logged in .

Comment: @DanielK By username i mean any random user from the database. It is displaying the username of a user previously stored in the database. I just want to retrieve the user who is currently logged in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this a couple of different ways. From the login activity just pass the current username through the intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,HomePageActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(String currentUserNameKey, currentUsername);
startActivity(intent);
```

or in the database that contains the usernames & passwords, create a new column for the table labeled `isCurrentUser` & set it to `true` for the current user when you log in & then when you're in the home page activity just query the database for the user that whose `isCurrentUser` value is `true`. Here is some sample code:

```
DBHelper dbhelper = new DBHelper(this);
SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.query(Table, 
    username, 
    isCurrentUser + " = ? ",
    new String []{"true"},
    null, null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
String currentUsername = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("username"));
```